# Windows XP doesn't recognise 2 TB Seagate external drive

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive

I recently had to re-install Windows XP after a failure, and now my 2 TB Seagate external hard drive is not recognised in My Computer. All data is still on the drive, I just can't access it.

I went to Seagate's site and it suggests downloading a program called 7-Zip, get the data off the external drive and reformat. All well and good, but I want it back to where it was before the reloading of XP.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Seagate's site recommended *7-Zip* for *data recovery*? Where?

Comment: Have you installed all updates and service packs?

Answer (score 2):

I have also seagate 1TB  hard drive that I for my laptop LG LM70  with  XP pro on it ..   BIOS dont detect this hard drive ..  or XP pro wont it recognize like external USB storage.

Solution to the problem is software from Seagate download page called SeaToolsDOS223ALL ISO CD.

Here are the instructions

1. download  HP format tool  (XP format dont work it has some bug). Format USB pen drive to FAT32
2. USB stick or pen drive
3. Seagate hard disk  1TB or other capacity
4. laptop that you can put Seagate 1TB  inside the laptop. Software cannot detect hard disk on USB external case
5. "Yumi" tool  for burning ISO to USB pen drive (choose unlisted ISO from RAM)
6. Boot from USB pen drive
7. Load blue Seagate software screen to change manualy  LBA settings. LBA settings are "FAKE SIZE of GB hard disk". Dont worry if you dont know what is LBA . just change numbers LBA to lower GB size you can see this number on every hard drive sticker

Take that Seagate 1TB hard disk and put to old laptos with old BIOS restriction. Ten you can install XP pro on it . or use ti like External  USB hard disk ..  I usually  put 120 GB fake GB size .. and it will show you on your "My computer". Now I have new samsung laptop with Windows 8 on it. And if you want to use full capacity 1 TB like USB external hard drive, you will need to change it in Seagate software to the LBA orginal size number - but  you will not that use on XP pro because it will not show on your "My Computer".

Answer (score 0):

Check Device Manager, Do you see it on there? or the a yellow '!' '?' if so than you might need some drivers from seagate

Answer (score 0):

Use this website - troubleshooter solved for me - needed driver update.
ie look into devices, usb driver fault hightlighted, update driver via windows search.
here : http://support.seagate.com/kbimg/flash/211851/211851_EN.html